# Angular Material Table: Sorting not working while using other fields other than description

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I am trying to sort leave tables. While my field description is working, when I try to sort through other fields such as leave_type, leave_from, leave_to it is not working. Below is my code for .html file and .ts file

leave-form.html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource] = "leaveData" style="width: 100%" matSort>
          <ng-container  matColumnDef="sn"><input matInput  placeholder="Filter">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> SN. </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;"> {{i+1+(pageSize*pageIndex)}} </td>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container  matColumnDef="leaveType">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Leave Type </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef= "let element" > {{element.leave_type}} </td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Description </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef= "let element"> {{element.description}} </td>
          </ng-container>

           <ng-container matColumnDef="leaveFrom">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Leave From </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef= "let element"> {{element.start_date | date: 'MM dd, y' : 'UTC'}} </td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="leaveTo">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Leave To </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef= "let element"> {{element.end_date | date: 'MM dd, y' : 'UTC'}} </td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="appliedOn">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Applied Date </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef= "let element"> {{element.created_at | date: 'MM dd, y' : 'UTC'}} </td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container  matColumnDef="leaveStatus">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Leave Status </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef= "let element"> {{element.leave_status}} </td>
          </ng-container>

          <tr mat-header-row  *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let element;"></tr>
        </table>
```

leave-form.ts

```
 getLeaveData() { 
    this.leaveApi.getUserLeave()
      .subscribe((data: []) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.leaveData = new MatTableDataSource(data);
        this.leaveData.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.leaveData.sort = this.sort;
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the sort code line inside a 
`setTimeout(function() { this.leaveData.sort = this.sort; }, 1)`